# Recover address wallet

Tags: wallet, seed, address, private-key

How do I recover address wallet by use private-key?
Following solana doc, it just showing recover address by seed phrase, and I want to recover by private-key

Answer (score 3):

Code Snippet

Step 1: import lib:

```
import { bs58 } from "@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/utils/bytes";
import { web3 } from "@project-serum/anchor";
```

Step 2: Call function:

```
const getKeypair = await web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode("private-key"));
console.log(`public key: ${getKeypair.publicKey}`);
```

Also, you can just simply import the private key in your [Phantom Wallet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/phantom/bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjophhpkkoljpa?hl=en) and you are good to go. You will see your public address and digital assets right away.

[image]

Comment: oh, I want to recover by code as nodejs

Comment: ops let me edit my answer then